# BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator gives module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I am working with creating a python BEAM pipeline with Dataflow in Cloud Composer 2.0. I am using `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` for the same. Below is the code

```
setup_script = path.join(configuration.get('core', 'dags_folder'), "setup.py")

transform_items = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
        task_id="transform_items",
        runner="DataflowRunner",
        py_file=path.join(airflow_bucket, "src", "items", "items.py"),
        default_pipeline_options={
            "project": "test",
            "region": "us-central1",
            "num_workers": "1",
            "max_num_workers": "5",
            "setup_file": setup_script,
        },
        pipeline_options={
            
            "input": "gs://test/%s" % filename,
            "output": "usr_tank.test_items",
            "output_type": "bigquery",
            "bigquery_schema": path.join(airflow_schema, "items_schema", "items_schema.json")

        },

        dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
            job_name="transform_items",
            project_id="test",
            location="us-central1",
            gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        ),

        py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.34.0'],
        py_system_site_packages=True,
        py_interpreter="python3",
        dag=dag,
    )
```

And here is the part of my beam pipeline code

```
from dags.pipeline_jobs.beam_utils import (
    RenameFields,
    WriteCoerced,
    CsvRecordSource,
)

def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input", dest="input", required=True, help="Input file to process."
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output",
        dest="output",
        required=True,
        help="Output file to write results to.",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_type",
        dest="output_type",
        required=False,
        default="json",
        help="One of (json, bigquery)",
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--bigquery_schema",
        dest="bigquery_schema",
        required=False,
        default="json",
        help="One of (json, bigquery)",
    )

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    (
        p
        | "read" >> Read(CsvRecordSource(known_args.input))
        | "rename_columns" >> RenameFields(FIELD_RENAMES)
        | WriteCoerced(
            known_args.output,
            known_args.output_type,
            schema_path=known_args.bigquery_schema,
        )
    )

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Now the problem is whenever I am trying to run my pipeline it is not able to import the `dags.pipeline_jobs.beam_utils` modules and because of that the pipeline on Dataflow fails. I understand that `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` creates its python venv but that shouldn´t be a problem. Could somebody let me know what am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you share the error you get?

Comment: @tank Were you able to solve the problem with the dependencies? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: No I couldn't able to find the root cause for this issue, but for me adjusting the imports worked, i moved my pipeline code inside the dags folder and then it worked.